# Is there a way to import old android studio projects and make them work

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, version-control, migration

I'm learning flutter dev, and the lessons I'm following are from way back in 2019, and they've got the course resources on github and for each module we have to import them from version control(git), basically what we are importing is an already made project that contains required assets and some lines of code, but after importing the project, trying to run it runs into soooo many errors, like so many, these errors have to do with the version of android studio they were built from, so far, I've been able to go through about 4 modules by manually creating a new project myself and just downloading the assets myself, copying the already-made code and manually adding the image assets for my icon, stuff like that, but it's getting stressful, and I wanted to know if there was a way to import very old android studio projects and somehow migrate them to match the same version of android studio I'm using, I've tried the tutorial on the migration documentation, and so far after migrating(basically playing around with manifest files and mainactivity, I still get the same ole errors, and can't run my project, Question is, how can I migrate old projects properly

MY ERROR

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

```
 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
 Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\paula\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\41a83d0cf61e3d2ab42ea706b65148ab\transformed\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
 Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\paula\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\bb9a53f8c4dc071c681fa071739dc70b\transformed\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1